# rails migration - update column with constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

How to add new column and update its value from another table's column with conditions ?

I'm having two tables named `user`

```
id: integer
name: string
preferred_communication_channel_id: integer  // stores the id of communication_channel
```

and table `communication_channel` stores different communication channels like Email,Telephone,etc.. of `user`

```
id: integer
user_id:  integer 
type: string
```

Now I need to add new column `communication_mode` in the `user` table

And update the column `communication_mode` value from `communication_channel.type` with some constraints

Here goes the **mysql version of the update**

```
update user as p
join communication_channel as cc 
on p.preferred_communication_channel_id = cc.id and p.id=cc.user_id and cc.type="Telephone" 
set p.communication_mode=3
```

I've created a migration to add new column but **how to implement this query in rails migration ?**

Please correct me if I missed anything

Answer (score 0):

In migrations you can just write `execute "SELECT * FROM bananas"` and the SQL will be executed!